# Get Elements from String List in order of Occurrence in provided string

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have List of strings as below.

```
List<string> MyList = new List<string> { "[FirstName]", "[LastName]", "[VoicePhoneNumber]", "[SMSPhoneNumber]" };
```

I need to get all the elements from the List if exist in string in order. For example my string is

```
 string MessageContent  = Hello [LastName] [FirstName]There, this message is for [SMSPhoneNumber]
```

Right now I am doing

```
var Exists = MyList.Where(MessageContent.Contains);
```

This new list have all the items from MyList which occured in MessageContent string but not in order.
How i can get occurrence in order in string?

Desired List as per example is  = { "[LastName]","[FirstName]","[SMSPhoneNumber]" }

Comment: I guess here it would be better to use regex, rather than LINQ. You can write regex and pull out all necessary strings. Something like ```"\[\w+\]"``` will be enough to capture all strings in format like "[foo]"

Comment: @Neistow I did it with Linq as var Exists = MyList.Where(MessageContent.Contains).OrderBy(s => MessageContent.IndexOf(s));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `IndexOf` to determine position (and thereby order) as well as existence to avoid searching `MessageContent` twice at the expense of sorting the answer:

```
var ans = MyList.Select(w => new { w, pos = MessageContent.IndexOf(w) })
                .Where(wp => wp.pos >= 0)
                .OrderBy(wp => wp.pos)
                .Select(wp => wp.w)
                .ToList();
```

However, if a field may appear more than once, or if you think avoiding the repeated scanning of `MessageContent` is faster than multiple `IndexOf` (once per `MyList` member) (probably not) and avoiding the sort, then you can invert the search (using `Span` to avoid generating lots of `String`s):

```
var ans2 = Enumerable.Range(0, MessageContent.Length-MyList.Select(w => w.Length).Min())
            .Select(p => MyList.FirstOrDefault(w => MessageContent.AsSpan().Slice(p).StartsWith(w)))
            .Where(w => w != null)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank You, I didn't think about the repeat scenario. Your second answer what i needed. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I did it Using

```
var Exists = MyList.Where(MessageContent.Contains).OrderBy(s => MessageContent.IndexOf(s));
```